# Cannot read property '$$phase' of null - AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, phase

for some reason I get this error while splicing an object from an array that lives in the $scope:

> Cannot read property '$$phase' of null

here's the code:

```
$scope.deleteThis = function (index) {
            $scope.$parent.accounts.splice(index, 1);
        }
```

I call this function on ng-click.

*Note:
This doesn't break anything ui wise or functionality wise, just appears in the console.*

Thanks!

Comment: What version of angularjs are you using? I'm using version 1.6.6 and it was throwing the error and breaking my app. I switched to a newer version and it disappeared.

Comment: Two years ago it was Angular 1.3.19 :D